# Call python script with arguments from java

Tags: java, python

I would like to call a python script from java using ScriptEngine but I am not sure how to add arguments

From command line it is something like: `python test.py language 10 "some text"`
where language, 10, "some text" are the args that will be given by user.

Here is a piece of code that I want to modify (refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10097910/682661))

```
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); //ouput will be stored here

 ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
 ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();

 context.setWriter(writer); //configures output redirection
 ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("python");
 engine.eval(new FileReader("test.py"), context);
 System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Comment: You can also do that by `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test.py language 10 \"some text\"");` as seen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756721/calling-python-from-java-tomcat6-as-sub-process

Comment: thanks for the comment. Yes, I know that but I wonder if it can be done using the script engine.

Answer (score 0):

By going through the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html), it seems this may be achieved by using `put()`:

```
// rest of your code
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("python");
engine.put(ScriptEngine.ARGV, array_of_strings);
engine.eval(new FileReader("test.py"), context);
// rest of your code
```

Where `array_of_strings` is an array of strings to be used as the arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that but it throws NullPointerException

Comment: @Daisy Which variable is null?

Comment: it referes to this line: engine.put(ScriptEngine.ARGV, array_of_strings);

Comment: @Daisy did you actually initiate a strings array?