# Send parms to python script form java with jython

Tags: java, jython

Hello I want to pass argument to python script in Java with Jython i have this code:

```
public static void pyCode(String argumentOne) throws FileNotFoundException, ScriptException {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); //ouput will be stored here

    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();

    context.setWriter(writer); //configures output redirection
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("python");
    engine.eval(new FileReader("main.py"), context);
    System.out.println(writer.toString());
}
```

I need to execute the python script like `main.py arg1` or to pass the String  input to the main.py file with will be used in the file.
I just found Jython and I can't see proper example in the documentation.

Comment: Looks like it would be easier running an actual python interpreter as an external process instead. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: I can the point here is I need to run the python script pass the argument and catch back print result back to java

Comment: You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37028938/call-python-script-with-arguments-from-java) (a duplicate).

Comment: No problem. I didn't try it out, but by reading the documentation made me confident enough to post it as a comment/possible-solution.